# How to send variables to Bramus Router

Tags: php, jwt, router

I have an API backend that is using the Bramus PHP router and validates JWTs from Auth0. This all works fine but I'm looking to expand the functionality and derive additional information from the JWT that I can then pass to the API calls.

That is, when a user makes an API call they send the user ID as a variable in the URL. However, this value is already in the JWT, so for security's sake, I want to pull the user ID out of the JWT rather than have it passed to through the URL.

Here is a snippet of the routing code I'm trying to use:

```
....
  $router->before('GET|POST', '/api.*', function() use ($app) {
    $userid = '12345';
  });

  // Check for read:messages scope
  $router->before('GET', '/api/private-scoped', function() use ($app) {
    if (!$app->checkScope('read:messages')){
      header('HTTP/1.0 403 forbidden');
      header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
      echo json_encode(array("message" => "Insufficient scope."));
      exit();
    }
  });

  $router->get('/api/users/get-info/(\w+)', function($userid) use ($app) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($app->getUserInfo($userid));
  });

  $router->get('/api/users/test', function() {
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode(array("user" => $userid));
  });
....
```

When I visit `/api/users/test` I get the following response:

```
{
    "user": null
}
```

How can I get variable `$userid` to pass into the router so I can use it in other functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're looking at here is a PHP scoping issue, not a specific [`bramus/router`](https://github.com/bramus/router/) – *which I'm the author of* – issue. Since you define `$user` inside the before callable, it's only available inside its current scope (e.g. between the `{` and the `}` of the function). Therefore you cannot access it outside of said function.

There are several ways to solve this. Since I see you already inject an `$app` variable into the before callback and other functions, I suggest you store the `$userid` onto `$app` and always read it from there.

Something like this:

```
....
  $router->before('GET|POST', '/api.*', function() use ($app) {
    $app->set('userid', '12345');
  });

  // Check for read:messages scope
  $router->before('GET', '/api/private-scoped', function() use ($app) {
    if (!$app->checkScope('read:messages')){
      header('HTTP/1.0 403 forbidden');
      header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
      echo json_encode(array("message" => "Insufficient scope."));
      exit();
    }
  });

  $router->get('/api/users/get-info/(\w+)', function($userid) use ($app) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($app->getUserInfo($userid));
  });

  $router->get('/api/users/test', function() use ($app) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode(array("user" => $app->get('userid')));
  });
....
```

Comment: Of course! Sometimes I get stuck on a problem and can't see the forest for the trees. Thank you!